# SOA implementation and deployment in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, soa

Can someone please let me know how we can implement and deploy SOA-based applications in .NET. I am .Net developer and pretty familiar with Web services and web APIs, also familiar with SOA architecture and concept. but not sure how I can deploy each web service independently without the need for deployment of the whole project.

Any guidance would be appreciated
Regards,
Zeynab

Comment: You build script should create separate build packages for each of the service and deployment pipeline should deploy the packages to their target location.

Comment: Thank you, will try that